# Getting syntax error using javascript some method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting one error. I am using javascript some method to reject some duplicate value but getting syntax error.I am explaining my code below.

```js
var outputList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < specialImages[0]['special'].length; i++) {
  if (!outputList.some(x => x.image === specialImages[0]['special'][i].image)) {
    var data = {
      image: specialImages[0]['special'][i].image,
      gallery_image: specialImages[0]['special'][i].gallery_image,
      comment: specialImages[0]['special'][i].comment
    };
    outputList.push(data);
  }
```

In the above code i am getting this error in this `if (!outputList.some(x => x.image === specialImages[0]['special'][i].image))` line. Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: maybe your user agent does not support arrow functions.

Comment: @NinaScholz : Yes,this error is affecting IE and Safari like browser. But working fine in chrome. Is there any solution ?

Comment: @subhra for your ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your user agent does not support arrow functions.

Replace arrow function

```
if (!outputList.some(x => x.image === specialImages[0]['special'][i].image)) {
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

with classic function

```
if (!outputList.some(function (x) { return x.image === specialImages[0]['special'][i].image; })) {
```